# Update database ManytoOne relationship (Spring Boot + MVC +Thymeleaf)

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I have two entity class.one is PhaseEntity and another is TaskEntity. PhaseId will be the foreign key of TaskEntity class. I can create and save the value to the database but cannot update the database.
Portion of TaskEntity class:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="phaseId")
    private PhaseEntity phaseEntity;
```

Controller class:

```
public class TaskController {
    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;
    @Autowired
    private PhaseService phaseService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/task/create",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createForm(Model model,Principal principal){
        model.addAttribute(new TaskEntity());
        model.addAttribute("body", "task/task-create");
        model.addAttribute("generaltaskDto",new GeneralTaskDto());
        model.addAttribute("phaseEntities", phaseService.phaseList());
        return "layouts/default";

    }
@RequestMapping(value="/task/create",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createFormPost(Model model,GeneralTaskDto generaltaskDto,BindingResult result){
        TaskEntity taskAndPhase=generaltaskDto.getTaskEntity();
taskAndPhase.setPhaseEntity(phaseService.getPhaseByPhaseId(generaltaskDto.getPhaseId()));
        taskService.saveTask(taskAndPhase);
        return "redirect:/task/list";
    }
@GetMapping(value="/task/update/{id}")
    public String updateTask(Model model,@PathVariable String id){
        TaskEntity taskEntity= taskService.getTaskId(Integer.parseInt(id));
        model.addAttribute("body", "task/task-create");
        model.addAttribute("phaseEntities", phaseService.phaseList());
        return "layouts/default";
        }
```

GeneraltaskDto class:

```
 public class GeneralTaskDto {
        private TaskEntity taskEntity=new TaskEntity();
        private Integer phaseId;
        public TaskEntity getTaskEntity() {
            return taskEntity;
        }
        public void setTaskEntity(TaskEntity taskEntity) {
            this.taskEntity = taskEntity;
        }
        public Integer getPhaseId() {
            return phaseId;
        }
        public void setPhaseId(Integer phaseId) {
            this.phaseId = phaseId;
        }


}
```

[here is the client page of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6I1T.png)

can anyone help plz how to update the database with controller request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding these lines in your controller under `updateTask` method after `TaskEntity taskEntity= taskService.getTaskId(Integer.parseInt(id));` line.

```
PhaseEntity phaseEntity=taskEntity.getPhaseEntity();
generaltaskDto.setTaskEntity(taskEntity);
generaltaskDto.setPhaseId(phaseEntity.getPhaseId());
model.addAttribute("generaltaskDto", generaltaskDto);
```